# How to make pop up blockers allow your popup windows?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

How to make pop up blockers allow your popup windows?

Comment: you tagged your question with jquery and javascript. You mean jquery popups i assume?

Comment: ....or "How to make anti-virus software allow your virus to infect a machine?"

Comment: Care to be more specific? Most blocker allowed explicit user triggred popups.

Comment: This is a case of think before asking!

Comment: I'm the the only one who knows how and I'll sell you the knowledge if you send a self-addressed legal sized envelope containing the amount of $10K to PO Box 666.

Comment: Rob - you miss the point, totally.

Comment: No, you missed the point. Some pop-ups are legit, and are used quite often. He didn't ask "How can I make malicious popups" did he? No. He simply asked how to make them work, and its quite possible he's trying to make them for a legit reason. But instead of coming in and helping him, you come in here and be a total dick, and thats highly unnecessary. This is supposed to be a place where people can get the help they seek, not get flamed for it. Be a bit more mature, guy.

Comment: Perhaps the poster should make this clear, no?

Comment: Perhaps you should be more of an optimist and assume that, instead of assume he's trying to do something illegit.

Comment: Listen here kids, don't make me pull this popup over! *shake fist*

Comment: @Rob (the other one, not me!), "Be a bit more mature", perhaps you should start with yourself there - the language you used isn't big, isn't clever and certainly isn't mature.

Comment: @Rob (Not talking to myself, I swear), Language has nothing to do with it. Coming in and flaming someone for simply asking a question is quite immature, as well as assuming its for illegitimate reasons.

Comment: @Rob, that'd be why one of the upvotes on this question was from me. Assume, ass, u, me, etc :) That said, it looks like you're removed the comment that contained the most offensive language, so fair-dos for that :)

Comment: @Rob, well I never removed any comment so hm

Comment: I am trying to display a PDF from within php which is called by an Angular app, and I feel it is not working because of the same issue the questioner has.  If anybody else has another explanation or solution, I am interested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, by popping them up from within the event handler of a user-generated event. For instance, if you have a link and the user explicitly clicks it and you raise a popup from the `onclick` handler on the link, most popup blockers will allow the popup because of the user's explicit action. In contrast, popups from the `window.load` event, or code executing as a result of a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` call, will typically be suppressed.

Somewhat OT, but: If you can avoid using a pop-up, I would. I'd say (unscientifically) that 95-99% or so of the use-cases where people think they need a pop-up, there's a better design solution. But the answer above is there for those 1-5% situations. :-)

Comment: @T.J. It's downvote Wednesday? That explains the anonymous downvote I got earlier. Does that mean we get 2 for 1 movie tickets at the expense of having our answers downvoted? ;-)

Comment: @T.J. It's Wednesday? Shit I missed Justified last night.

Comment: Hmm...suddenly I got down-voted on a few of my questions that are quite old. I feel a vigilante in the works.

Answer (score 4):

Users have to set that manually. Imagine what would happen if web apps were allowed to override popup blockers.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. It's up to the user to configure their software to allow pop ups. As a general rule, pop ups generated by user input (i.e. clicking on a button) is usually allowed by most pop up blockers. But this isn't a definitive rule and we can't change it programmatically. If we could it would make pop up blockers useless.

Answer (score 4):

You should use a [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), which the popup blocker will not affect.

Comment: he is asking about popup windows but dialog box

Answer (score 3):

Display a message nicely asking the user to unblock your popups. Obviously the whole point to popup blockers is so you, the site developer, can't forcibly defeat them.

Answer (score 2):

In your own browser … it depends on the browser and/or third party popup blocker.

When you have no control over the client — open the popup in response to a user generated event (such as `onclick`).

Comment: This is evil, and you know it.

Comment: Popups in response to user generated events are not evil. Ugly? Yes. Usually a suboptimal design? Absolutely. Evil? No.

Comment: The word "evil" is used far too freely these days.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to make them appear on your page rather than as an actual pop-up (which you can do pretty easily with jquery).  If that's not appropriate in your case, asking nicely is a good option.